# I'm using Richard Stanton/texintro jf.bst but the citation “et al.” for more than 3 authors doesn't work for me

Tags: citing, custom-bib

I'm writing after 5 days trying to understand why it's not working. I'm using texstudio and writing a paper for the Journal of Finance. I am using the jf.bst  (save in the same file as the tex file and as the bib file. I am using the `\cite` command and using the command `\bibliographystyle{jf}`. Still, after trying multiple times, If I have a paper to cite with more than 3 authors, the cite command will show me the list fo all the authors, although the bst file saying that it should show me 3 names and a year. could anyone help me with that?. I will highly appreciate that.

Comment: You should include the source code of what you're trying to do.  I believe the answer is simple, but I need to see what you're doing so my answer would be as close to your attempt as possible.

Comment: \usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
===============
\begin{document}
\title{\Large{}}
\author{.}}
\setcounter{page}{0}
%===================================================================
\newpage
\onehalfspacing
\noindent  slowed the recovery (\cite{mian2011house}, \cite{mian2013household}, \cite{mian2017household}). As a result, Policy makers in many.\footnote{\cite*{Alam2019digging} }..
%BIBLIOGRAPHY===============================

\newpage
\begin{doublespacing}   % Double-space the bibliography
 \bibliographystyle{jf}
\bibliography{RiskWeights}
\end{doublespacing}

Comment: By the way - if I change the \cite to \citet - it stays the same. So Im not sure what is the problem.

Comment: @Alex is this what you asked for?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Whether or not `et al` is used in the bibliography is controlled by the bst file. If this is the behaviour that you are getting then it is probably the behaviour that the journal wants, so you should not try to change this. This said, if you still want help then please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) (MWE) as part of the question and *not* as a comment. The MWE shoud compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem, so you should add a reference with 5 authors to the MWE. Finally, where can we find `jf.bst`?

Comment: It is not the journal official bst. file. It is a file that a professor wrote and published online. You can find it here: https://www.overleaf.com/project/5e25e5767671ff0001b528ad

Comment: I'm also stuck with the same problem this night. http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/ Seems professor Richard forgot to add the reference code in .tex files.